# iPhone SDK TV Output

Tags: iphone, dock, television

does someone know something about TV output with dock connector.

I would like to create a new application that use TV output. Is there some official API/documentation?

Thx,
Paolo

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll need to check out the [Made for iPod](http://developer.apple.com/ipod/) program.  You can get access to everything you need to develop devices and software to attach to the iPod/iPhone dock connector.